# Get names of all tables. Doctrine + Codeigniter

Tags: php, doctrine, codeigniter-2

I need to find a doctrine function that allow me make a query of all the names of the tables of my database.

I have found solutions, for example this one. 
(You need to put the entity to the function and it will return the name of the table.)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$tableName = $em->getClassMetadata('StoreBundle:User')->getTableName();
```

This is not what I need. 
What I would do in SQL would be:

```
show tables in database_name;
```

It returns the names of all the tables in my database.

I need to do that using Doctrine.

Answer (score 6):

as this is tagged with codeigniter, i will give the codeigniter answer.

```
$this->db->list_tables();
```

Comment: I don't know if I should accept this answer as the correct answer, even though it returns the list of the tables, it's not implemented using doctrine. =/.